# How to prevent hover effect on a ul elm inside of li elm?

Tags: css

First, see the code below:

```css
ul.parent li:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

/* ul.parent li:hover .child{
  background-color: white;
} */
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li><a href=""> App </a></li>
  <li>
     <a href=""> Components </a>
     <ul class="child">
       <li><a href=""> Badge </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Dropdown </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Navbar </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Modal </a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is when I hover on components the ul child list also changes the background-color as expected. But I don't want it, When I hove on components only this li should be changed not the ul list.
Again, when I hover on it then I can change the ul background color as I need (for me it makes a lot of problems).

How can I do this stuff? Advance Thanks.

Comment: `ul.parent  a:hover{ background-color: red; }`  ??

Comment: Change the `background-color` of the anchor tag only. `ul.parent li a:hover { background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can color only the `a` inside

```css
ul li:hover>a{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li><a href=""> App </a></li>
  <li>
     <a href=""> Components </a>
     <ul class="child">
       <li><a href=""> Badge </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Dropdown </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Navbar </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Modal </a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background` property to the anchor tags, not the list items. You can then unset the color for nested anchor tags (or set a different color or effect):

```css
ul.parent > li:hover > a{
  background-color: red;
}

ul.parent > li:hover ul.child a{
  background: unset;
}

ul.child > li:hover a{
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>
      <a href=""> App </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href=""> Components </a>
     <ul class="child">
       <li><a href=""> Badge </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Dropdown </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Navbar </a></li>
       <li><a href=""> Modal </a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```